# Session and get method in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, session, hbm

I have the following project and its returning "null" .. How to resolve it?

My java class :

```
public class UpdateExample {  
    /**
   * @param args
    */
     public static void main(String[] args) {  
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
         Session sess = null;  
         try {  
            SessionFactory fact = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();  
            sess = fact.openSession();  
             Transaction tr = sess.beginTransaction();  


            Insurance ins = (Insurance)sess.get(Insurance.class, new Long(1));  
           ins.setInsuranceName(2);    
           ins.setInvestementAmount(20000);  
           ins.setInvestementDate(new Date());  
           sess.update(ins);  
           tr.commit();   
           sess.close();  
           System.out.println("Update successfully!");  
        }  
        catch(Exception e){
           System.out.println("If null " + e.getMessage());  
        }  
   }  
 }  


public class Insurance {  

    private long insuranceName;  
    private double investementAmount;  
    private Date investementDate;  

    public long getInsuranceName() {  
        return insuranceName;  
     }  

    public void setInsuranceName(long insuranceName) {  
        this.insuranceName = insuranceName;
     }

    public double getInvestementAmount() {
        return investementAmount;
     }

    public void setInvestementAmount(double investementAmount) {
       this.investementAmount = investementAmount;
     }

    public Date getInvestementDate() {
       return investementDate;
    }

    public void setInvestementDate(Date investementDate) {
       this.investementDate = investementDate;
    }  
}
```

insurance.hbm.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>   
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">  

<hibernate-mapping>  

    <class name="Insurance" table="Insurance">  
        <id name="insuranceName" type="long" column="InsuranceName">  
            <generator class="assigned" />  
        </id>  

        <property name="investementAmount">  
            <column name="InvestementAmount" />  

        </property>  

       <property name="investementDate">  
           <column name="InvestementDate" />  
       </property>  

    </class>  


 </hibernate-mapping>
```

So the output i get is:

Hibernate: select insurance0_.InsuranceName as Insuranc1_0_, insurance0_.InvestementAmount as Investem2_0_0_, insurance0_.InvestementDate as Investem3_0_0_ from Insurance insurance0_ where insurance0_.InsuranceName=?
If null null

Please suggest the solution.

Thanks
Sneha

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say exactly without the stack trace, but most probably

```
 Insurance ins = (Insurance)sess.get(Insurance.class, new Long(1));
```

returns null (no such record in the database) therefore the next line produces NullPointerException. I would suggest to add

```
catch(Exception e){
   System.out.println("If null " + e.getMessage());  
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

to the catch clause in order to see where NPE happens.

Comment: yeaj.. i have that catch and it's going there only..but why is it throwing that error when i have the record in table?

Comment: Maybe the ID column mapping is wrong? Maybe the type is not long in the DB? Can you dump DDL here and the database record?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest few changes

Change type:

```
<id name="insuranceName" type="java.lang.Long" column="InsuranceName">  
      <generator class="assigned" />  
</id>
```

And in insurance class(POJO)

```
private Long insuranceName;
```

Try this.

**Update:** I tried your mapping it works, ensure that you have insurance data by id 1 and hibernate.cfg.xml is proper.